# Plotting cdf and regular graph in same axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, math

I have a vector with 1000 random numbers called v.  I also have a vector, called x that represents the domain of which the numbers in v are generated, and another vector y that has the numbers of the cdf of the values in v.  I know that I can do plot(x,y); and get a smooth function of the (non-empirical) cdf, and I also know that I can do cdfplot(v) to get a function of the empirical cdf.

My question is: How can I get these plots on the same set of axis?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: try using the `hold` function ([link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either generate data for an empirical cdf plot using [`ecdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ecdf.html) or plot it directly with `cdfplot` like you mentioned. I would recommend using `cdfplot` since it sets up a few more things, such as a grid:

```
hFig = figure;
cdfplot(v);
hold all;
plot(x, y);
```

And as a bonus! Consider showing the X axis in logarithmic units, whichever reveals the data the best for you:

```
hAxes = get(hFig, 'CurrentAxes'); 
set(hAxes, 'XScale', 'log')
```